# What does Reflect.construct let us do that wasn't doable before?

Tags: javascript, reflection

I'm trying to find a good reason to use `Reflect.construct` to achieve something noteworthy that I could not achieve before.

I'm not looking for an answer like the [one here](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/metaprogramming-in-es6-part-2-reflect/#reflectconstruct--target-argumentslist--constructortocreatethis-), because that example don't seem to be very useful. For example, why would I write

```
function greetingFactory(name) {
  return Reflect.construct(Greeting, [name]);
}
```

when I can just write

```
function greetingFactory(name) {
  return new Greeting(name);
}
```

?

Do you know any notable use cases for `Reflect.construct`?

EDIT: Seems like I may have found a use case myself, but I'm not sure if it is solid and if it won't fall apart, but basically it seems like I can make `new.target` work with ES5-style classes by writing them like this:

```
function Foo() {
  console.log('Foo, new.target:', new.target)
  this.name = "foo"
}

Foo.prototype.sayHello = function sayHello() {
  return this.name
}

function Bar() {
  console.log('Bar, new.target:', new.target)
  let _ = Reflect.construct(Foo, [], new.target)
  _.name = _.name + " bar"
  return _
}

Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype)

Bar.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  return "Hello " + Foo.prototype.sayHello.call(this) + "!"
}

function Baz() {
  console.log('Baz, new.target:', new.target)
  let _ = Reflect.construct(Bar, [], new.target)
  _.name = _.name + " baz"
  return _
}

Baz.prototype = Object.create(Bar.prototype)

Baz.prototype.sayHello = function() {
  return Bar.prototype.sayHello.call(this) + " Hello again!"
}

let baz = new Baz

console.log(baz.sayHello())
```

The cool thing about it is that `this` is as expected inside the prototype methods!

Comment: I don't think it's about *enabling* things that haven't not been possible before, but rather providing a unified API for these kind if "meta" operations.

Comment: @FelixKling I suppose APIs as shortcuts for lengthier ways of doing something are valid, but I suppose I'm also curious to know if `Reflect.construct` solves any problems aside from possibly being a shortcut.

Comment: @FelixKling I updated my answer, I think I might have found a use case.

Comment: *"The cool thing about it is that this is as expected inside the prototype methods!"* It would be anyway, thanks to the way you're calling them. All that using `Reflect.construct` does in the above is ensure that `new.target` is set for the calls to `Bar` and `Foo` (which could indeed be useful; that's basically a generalized version of my #3).

Answer (score 5):

The only three use cases I know of for `Reflect.construct` are:

1. Using it within a Proxy [`construct` trap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/construct) to get the default behavior (or to get slightly-modified default behavior).
2. Using it to avoid creating and using an iterator when you need to call a constructor function using an array whose elements need to be passed as discrete arguments. You *can* just do

   ```
   t = new Thing(...theArray);
   ```

   but that involves creating and using an iterator, whereas

   ```
   t = Reflect.construct(Thing, theArray);
   ```

   doesn't use an iterator, which is much less work (not that it usually matters; this is for a situation where you know time is crucial). (Instead of an iterator, `construct` just uses `length` and directly accesses the `0`, `1`, etc. properties.)

   Neither of those options was available before ES2015. Instead, you had to do this:

   ```
   t = Thing.apply(Object.create(Thing.prototype), theArray);
   ```

   which worked with ES5 constructor functions. (It wouldn't work with an ES2015+ constructor function created via `class`, but you don't need it to — you'd use one of the two options above instead.)
3. Using it to avoid using `class` when constructing an instance of a subtype of `Error` or `Array` or a web component (some people [don't like to use `class`](https://medium.com/@WebReflection/a-case-for-js-classes-without-classes-9e60b3b5992), and there are good arguments for that in projects that may need to be transpiled). (That said, `Reflect.construct` can't be perfectly polyfilled, either.)

Comment: Interesting. Any thoughts on the following `Reflect.construct` polyfill? https://github.com/Mr0grog/newless/blob/master/newless.js#L28

Comment: @trusktr - Thoughts in what regard?

Comment: F.e. How complete it is and what features are missing (f.e. that can't be polyfilled)?

Comment: @trusktr - In a pure ES5 env., you can't correctly subclass `Error` or `Array` and so using `Reflect.construct` with `Error` or `Array` when you provide a `new.target` (the third arg) doesn't (and can't) work. In an ES5 environment with `__proto__` (SpiderMonkey in Firefox going back years, Chakra in IE11), you can, but that particular polyfill doesn't try to. Not criticising, just observing. FWIW: https://jsbin.com/qosoqoyazu/1/edit That 1. Tries `class` if supported, 2. Tries `Reflect.construct` if supported, 3. Uses that polyfill's ES5 path, then 4. Uses polyfill + `__proto__` if supported.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to sort out a useful application of the `Reflect.construct` as well. I think I may have found something but it would be nice to bounce the idea off other people on a similar path.

What I was thinking is that you could use `Reflect.construct` to *wedge* a `[[Prototype]]` between the instantiated object and it's intended `[[Prototype]]`. This would allow you to shadow properties and methods that belong to the intended `[[Prototype]]` without being too intrusive.

```
function Wedge() {};

Wedge.prototype = Object.create(String.prototype);

Wedge.prototype.toUpperCase = function () {
    return "nope";
}

let someString = Reflect.construct(String, ['Foo Bar'], Wedge)

someString.toUpperCase() // "nope"
```

Comment: Interesting. Is this also doable with `Object.setPrototypeOf` and `obj.__proto__`?

Answer (score 1):

It's late on the topic, but it is in fact possible to properly subclass native classes in ES5 code. It looks like this:

```js
//ES6-class version
class MyArray extends Array {
  peekLast() {
    return this[this.length - 1];
  }
}

//ES5-class version
function MyArray() {
  //No need to use new since that instance gets discarded
  var retval = new Array();
  retval.__proto__ = MyArray.prototype; //This is the key line
  //Do any other initialization to retval here.
  return retval;
}
MyArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype, {
  constructor: {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: MyArray
  },
  peekLast: {
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: function peekLast() { return this[this.length - 1]; }
  }
});
MyArray.__proto__ = Array;
```

I get that `__proto__` was never in the ES standard before ES6, but it was a defacto web standard that all major browsers and engines supported. That's what makes it possible.

Comment: Hi Ranando, you didn't use `Reflect.construct` in that example. Does that actually legitimately work? Are there no caveats that otherwise only the use of `class` or `Reflect.construct` could solve?

Comment: I came up with this a few months before the release of ES6. So at the time, there was no way I could use `Reflect.construct` or `class`. `class` was just syntax sugar before this proposal-class-fields came along. The trick to inheriting from native objects is to instantiate the native object and attach your own prototype chain to that object. This is precisely what both `class` and `Reflect.construct` do. It's also the reason why `this` isn't valid until after the call to `super`. The instance object is always created by the first ancestor, and `new.target` holds the prototype to use.

Comment: The only things outside of what I explained that `class` and `Reflect.construct` do are:

`class`: forces you into strict mode, simplifies prototype construction and inheritance, forces your constructor to require new, sets a few internal properties that aren't really relevant to the developer.

`Reflect.construct`: preforms the same process I described while also setting those same mostly irrelevant internal properties.

From a programming perspective, you get more concise code at the cost of a loss of control. Nothing more.

Comment: Is there not anything that `Reflect.construct` allows us to achieve that we couldn't before (internal properties aside)? I haven't tried it, but I suppose we can get Custom Elements to work with ES5 classes, by doing that same trick as with Array?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. As long as the engine provides access to either `__proto__` or `Object.setPrototypeOf()`, there is no unique use for `Reflect.construct`.

Answer (score 0):

It accepts the constructor whose prototype should be used in **Reflect.constructor** 3rd parameter.
Try this code below and take a look to the prototype in **array1Proto**. 
It set Array as constructor despite was Object/func1 at the beginning.

```js
    function func1(a, b, c) {
      this.sum = a + b + c;
    }
    
    const args = [1, 2, 3];
    const object1 = new func1(...args);
    const object2 = Reflect.construct(func1, args);
    const array1Proto = Reflect.construct(func1, args, Array);
    
    console.log(object1)
    console.log(object2)
    console.log(array1Proto)
```

Comment: How does this differ from setting the prototype manually with `Object.setPrototypeOf()` or `obj.__proto__ = ...`?